# java String format for a long integer with at least 10 characters

Tags: java, formatting

I have a long integer that I want to be able to print out and write to a csv file.
If I just write the string unformatted it prints 1.2345E9 instead of the full exact number.
What String.format() should I use so that this prints out every single digit correctly.

Comment: Which API you are using to export csv file? That API must have string/integer/date format methods, use them..Try to print the number in java code and see, i hope it will print the number correctly..

Comment: Just to be sure... Did you check the CSV content? Because MS Excel tends to format numbers that way, even if they're correctly listed in the CSV file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably just MS Excel formatting things "badly" for you. Check out this `test.csv` file here:

```
"COLUMN"
12345678901234567890
```

Opened in MS Excel

[image]

So check your CSV content. Probably, you don't have a Java formatting problem there

Answer (score 0):

You can format the cell content as per the need like number/currency/date/string etc.. by the API method you are using to create csv.

Answer (score 0):

To retain display pattern of numeric content from an spread sheet to a csv file, that value needs to be converted to text by using quotes.

**Example**:

```
CSV contents (when opened in a text editor) ->: 1234567890',"""1234567890""",1234567890
XLS displays them as ------------------------>: 1234567890',"""1234567890""",1.23E+09
```

Each cell's content is displayed based on the default value type as parsed by the Spread Sheet application.
Hence there is no way for CSV but surrounding a numeric value with quotes to retain desired string format.